# How to save web view state in fragment on orientation changed?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I save the web-view state in fragment with ViewModel in java. As this way:

```
public class PageViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<CustomWebView> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public void setWebView(CustomWebView webView) {
        liveData.setValue(webView);
    }
    public LiveData<CustomWebView> getWebView() {
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

In *onCreate* in Fragment and save current web-view state:

```
pageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
pageViewModel.setWebView((CustomWebView) view);
```

And finally in onConfigurationChanged in Fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    pageViewModel.getWebView().observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<CustomWebView>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(CustomWebView customWebView) {
            webView = customWebView;
        }
    });
}
```

So, When orientation is change, the web-view not reloading. But when I use this way in kotlin, The Webview not save state and it reloaded.

PageViewModel:

```
class PageViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val liveData = MutableLiveData<CustomWebView>()
    fun setWebView(webView: CustomWebView?) {
        liveData.value = webView
    }
    fun getWebView(): LiveData<CustomWebView?>? {
        return liveData
    }
}
```

In global variables: `private lateinit var pageViewModel: PageViewModel` and in onCreate method of fragment:

```
pageViewModel = ViewModelProvider(activity!!).get(PageViewModel::class.java)
pageViewModel.setWebView(view as CustomWebView)
```

And finally in onConfigurationChanged in Fragment:

```
 pageViewModel.getWebView()?.observe(requireActivity(), Observer { customWebView ->
        if (customWebView != null) {
            webView = customWebView
        }
    })
```

Can you help me? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is fine and it works well. I tested your code but in my app, *onConfigurationChanged* not ran. I searched for this problem and add this line to the activity tag in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

And then * onConfigurationChanged * was run.